# Erasing old system files

Tags: apt, upgrade

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS.

I know that after each upgrading process, there are some old files we can erase from our HDD (I don't know why this action isn't activated inside the upgrading process itself).

We can use the terminal line command: sudo apt purge linux-image.4.15.xx-nnnnnnnn to get this (nnnnnnnn could be "lowlatency" or "generic").

But, my question is about some files called: linux-headers.4.15.xx-nnnnnnnn and linux-modules.4.15.xx-nnnnnnnn.

Is it absolutely safely to erase them? Can we erase them without to hurt the system?

If these file can be safely erased... Why this action is not included into the upgrading process itself? Why we have to perform this manually?

Comment: That's four questions. Yes, kernel-header packages can be safely uninstalled...though if you use DKMS or other kernel-dependent services the package might get reinstalled as a dependency. Packages eligible for autoremoval *are* removed during the release-upgrade process. You must uninstall manually only if you installed the package manually. Some folks don't remember doing the manual install.

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` will remove unneeded packages, safely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safety depends because sometimes this is not safe and the following should explain why.

Those packages are not purged during the upgrading process because sometimes the system won't boot when you install a new kernel. If the system does not boot after upgrading the kernel, you can select an older kernel that will boot from your grub screen. These old kernels are usually available until you explicitly uninstall or purge them or use `apt autoremove`.

Also, you can run `sudo apt clean` and also `sudo apt autoclean` to remove cached deb packages.

Additionally, sometimes you might have modules in use that are self compiled and so these modules are still available to the user until the older kernels are uninstalled by the user. It is not uncommon for users to compile wifi driver modules or even proprietary display drivers and these can be critical.

So, if you have rebooted using a newer kernel and all of the modules and software you need work fine then the older kernels are probably not needed. If this is the case then, it is most likely safe to uninstall these using the `sudo apt purge linux-image.4.15.xx-nnnnnnnn` command or `sudo apt autoremove`. However, it is nice sometimes to have an older kernel available just in case you mess things up later on.